# React-native replace \n

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm currently working on a project with React-native and I have an issue with the following sentence where `\n` is rendered inside the screen:

```
Geweldig pand op geweldige locatie!\n\nDat mag je daadwerkelijk zo stellen...\n\nOp loopafstand van de Nachtegaalstraat en de Biltstraat tref je dit werkelijk bijzondere pand aan.
```

As you can see in the sentence there are `\n`, I know that react-native can't render `\n` and instead uses `{"\n"}`. But how do I replace the `\n` to a breakline?

This is my current code:

```
renderDescription() {
    let text = this.state.huisExtraInfo.offerText;

    if (this.state.showDescription) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    {text}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text numberOfLines={3} style={styles.description}>{text}</Text>
                <Button onPress={() => this.setState({showDescription: true})}><Icon name='caret-down'/> Lees de volledige beschrijving</Button>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

I have tried the following methods:
 Method one:

```
text.replace(/\n/g, "{'\n'}");
```

Method two:

```
{text.split(/\n/).map((item, key) => {
        return (
            <Text key={key}>
                {item} {"\n"}
            </Text>
            )
    })}
```

None of the methods that I have tried work, any suggestions?

Image for reference:
[Text on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYEV6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
export default function App() {
  const text ="Geweldig pand op geweldige locatie!\n\nDat mag je daadwerkelijk zo stellen...\n\nOp loopafstand van de Nachtegaalstraat en de Biltstraat tref je dit werkelijk bijzondere pand aan.";
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried the same thing as you did but it didn't work on my end. I forgot to mention that I get the text from state, but when I define the text as you do I get the same result but not if I use state. I updated the question with the code that I use currently.

Comment: For me its even working with state also can you please post the whole code?

Comment: Try this code <Text>{this.state.text.replace('<br/>', '\n')}</Text>

Comment: Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/qW7Hn7pn. I tried the method you said and it didn't work either...

Comment: Try to replace \n after let text = this.state.huisExtraInfo.offerText;That is after this line try this text=text.replace('\n','<br/>') or text = text.replace('\n','')

Comment: I tried the 2 things you suggested and it doesn't work either. I still get the same result... Here is how the code looks now: https://pastebin.com/tX7SseDh

Comment: Did you check what you are getting in the text after doing replace just console it and share the result

Comment: This is the output from the code i send before. https://pastebin.com/NVwFkBZM

Comment: Yeah I got it whats wrong is \n cannot be replaced like this use this it will work sure      
 text = text.split('\\n').join(' ') this will remove \n lines from your string use this line after          let text = this.state.huisExtraInfo.offerText;

Comment: Yes that was the fix! Thank you so much for taking your time helping me!